# Exception In boost-beast

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-beast, boost-beast-websocket

I use Boost::Beast and i got somme exception message for exemple : resolve: No such host is known.
I want in my code to  print i message more significant that can a simple user get a idea what this message means .
how i can do that?

that is the exemple that i chose to work with in the first but thy don't work for me

```
 if (ec && ec != beast::errc::not_connected) {
      beast::system_error{ ec };
      std::cout << "beast::errc::not_connected" << ec << " with explanatory message " << ec.message() << std::endl;
    }
    if (ec && ec != beast::errc::no_buffer_space) {
      beast::system_error{ ec };
      std::cout << "beast::errc::no_buffer_space" << ec << " with explanatory message " << ec.message() << std::endl;

    }
    if (ec && ec != beast::errc::timed_out) {
      beast::system_error{ ec };
      std::cout << "beast::errc::timed_out" << ec << " with explanatory message " << ec.message() << std::endl;

    }
    if (ec && ec != beast::errc::no_buffer_space) {
      beast::system_error{ ec };
      std::cout << "beast::errc::no_buffer_space" << ec << " with explanatory message " << ec.message() << std::endl;

    }
    if (ec && ec != beast::errc::stream_timeout) {
      beast::system_error{ ec };
      std::cout << "beast::errc::stream_timeout" << ec << " with explanatory message " << ec.message() << std::endl;

    }
```

Comment: Why `ec && ec != ...` ?  Surely you mean `ec && ec == ...`, right?

Comment: yes your right ,i forgot to change that, where i can found found list of error for exemple "resolve: No such host is known" to give a message more  significant for that error.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others, `ec && ec != CODE` needed to be `ec && ec == CODE`.

However, that conjunction is redundant: `ec && ec == CODE` is equivalent to `ec == CODE` (unless `!ec.failed()`).

I don't think any of the conditions are required:

```
    if (ec) {
        std::cout << ec.message() << "\n";
    }
```

That just prints the friendly message for any error:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78408d071c77e30d)**

```
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace beast = boost::beast;

int main() {
    for (auto code : {
             beast::errc::not_connected,
             beast::errc::no_buffer_space,
             beast::errc::timed_out,
             beast::errc::no_buffer_space,
             beast::errc::stream_timeout,
         })
    {
        boost::system::error_code ec = make_error_code(code);
        if (ec) {
            std::cout << ec.message() << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Transport endpoint is not connected
No buffer space available
Connection timed out
No buffer space available
Timer expired
```

### To the gist of the question

There will not be friendlier error descriptions for "your users" as they will always depend on your program's logic and domain. So it's on the programmer to translate any non-recoverable errors into user-friendly conditions.

E.g. there cannot ever be a useful "end-user" description for `no_buffer_space` since ... you know buffers interest programmers only. You might translate that into something like "System load exceeded" or "Simulation too large" or "Attachment is too large".

Comment: Cheers. welcome to StackOverflow. Please remember to [vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)